# Java add asterisks with counter

Tags: java

I have a counter variable and for every 3 input in the range from 1-5 I need to add an Asterisk to show the total. So if 7 answers in the range 1-5 occurred, it would only print out 2 Asterisks. I need to somehow take the counter total, put it in a loop I'm assuming and for every 3, add the asterisks to the total below.

```
if(value >= 1 && value <= 5){
     counter++;
}
```

The print out would look something like this

```
Answers from 1 - 5: ** // from 7 in this range
Answers from 1 - 5: *** // from 9 in this range
```

Comment: Looks like you are learning Java. You may want to use integer division to see how many asterisks to print instead of a lot of if-statements: `counter = value / 3;` will count how many 3s there are in `value`. Do you know how to print them?

Comment: I know how to print them out thats not the problem. For every 3 values in that range I need to "ADD" an asterisk to the total. That was the example I tried to show above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the correct result.

```
int value = counter / 3;
System.out.print("Answers from 1 - 5: ");
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    System.out.print("*");
System.out.println();
```

end should give you the correct result.

Given that the number you want is an integer it will store it as a whole number (e.g. 7/3 = 2). You can use System.out.print() to start the line, print on the same line as many asterisks you need and then end the line.

Hope this helps.